# terraform to launch and configure EC2 AD

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have 2 windows server AMIs :

the first one acts as a client (since as per my research, there is no windows 10 enterprise AMIs in AWS) and the second AMI has an AD.

I would like to create a terraform script that automatically creates EC2 instances from the AMIs, the script should also configure AD with domain and then make the windows member of domain.

Is that possible? if not, would that be possible to achieve using a user data script?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what exactly you need but the 2 resources you will need for sure are:

1.The ec2 resource is ***[aws_instance](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance)*** and is configured like:

```
resource "aws_instance" "my-ec2" {
  ami                    = "ami-058b1b7fe545997ae"
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id              = "your-subnet-id"

  availability_zone      = "your-availability_zone"
  vpc_security_group_ids = "your-security-group"

  tags = {
    Name        = "me"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

2. The AD resource is ***[aws_directory_service_directory](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/directory_service_directory)***

```
resource "aws_directory_service_directory" "my-ad" {
  name     = "corp.notexample.com"
  password = "SuperSecretPassw0rd"
  size     = "Small"

  vpc_settings {
    vpc_id     = "my-vpc-id"
    subnet_ids = [aws_subnet.foo.id, aws_subnet.bar.id]
  }

 connect_settings {
   customer_dns_ips  = ["A.B.C.D"]
   customer_username = "Admin"
   subnet_ids        = [aws_subnet.foo.id, aws_subnet.bar.id]
   vpc_id            = "my-vpc-id"
 }

  tags = {
    Name        = "me"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}
```